# Are new levels becoming available without any announcements in-game?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Yesterday I received an in-game notification that there were two new levels available for me to build.  One was a food level (Bongo's Sandwiches), and the other a residential level (Chiss Apartments).

Those were initially not available for building, and I waited until this morning and they were available (presumably due to a bug fix on the developer end).

Just for amusement, I started tapping on other types of floors and discovered that there was a new recreation level (Planetarium), ANOTHER residential level (Talz Apartments), and a new Imperial level available (Blaster Repair).

None of these three new floors provided any notification that they were available for building.  I know I didn't miss them being available previously because I have tapped on things randomly before, too without getting new levels.

[image: Notifier]  [image: Levels]  [image: levels]  [image: levels]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the answer from the iOS App Store.  As of update 1.3.0 (Feb 5th, 2014) It states there will be new levels **now and every Monday**

:  [image]

Comment: The first photo is from the Monday release.  For whatever reason the levels did not become available until Tuesday morning.  I was mostly posting this as a means of letting people know that there were additional levels to be had which might not be readily apparent.

Answer (score 1):

Your first image says

"New Levels have been released! Add Chiss Apts, Bongo's Sandwiches **and more**"

This implies that there was more than just those two levels.

Generally they release levels evenly, one of each type plus as many residential to allow for enough workers.  I'm guessing they just didn't have enough space to list them all in the notice.

Comment: My point in posting this above is to let people know that there were additional levels apart from the ones for which they've given notice.  I don't know that you can make any statement about the levels being released evenly.  The step-wise release of new levels has only begun with this new update.

Comment: But my point is that, despite not being specifically mentioned, the notice does say **AND MORE**.  Maybe it's incorrect to attribute the Tiny Tower standards, but in Tiny Tower, they do almost always release levels evenly.  Other than special event levels, I don't know that they've released new levels for this game yet.

Comment: Two of the residential levels were added during the weekend (Mustafar & Talz) along with the Imperial Marches retail level. There was some sort of in-game message at the time that said to come back Monday for more levels. I believe everything else was added on Monday.
The Tuesday unlock for you might have been a timezone thing? I believe it was unlocked later in the day on Monday for me...